# DuplicateKeyException even after removing unique constraints

Tags: java, db2, constraints, unique

I'm working on db2. I got one table, which contains some data:

```
Data | Value | Lang
```

To Data column of this table, was added unique constraint. However, now application CAN contain many rows for the same date. So, I removed constraint, but, after reorganization of table, restart of server it still throws exceptions when I want to add more than one row with the same Data.

Unfortunately I didn't create this table at first place, and I can't remove data from it :/

Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Thanks for you time!

Comment: It would be very useful if you provide the platform and version of DB2 you're running, DDL for the table and the error message you get when you try to insert the row.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? At what action does it happen? Your question is pretty vaque at the monent.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't thought this is important. Error message: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;WCSADMIN.XSALESREPORT, DRIVER=4.7.85. I'm using IBM WebSphere Commerce v7. But query I'm executing in console - if you want, I can also past exception from Java, but I'm pretty sure it is quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like there was index on this column also.

To check indexes:

```
select * from SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES where TBNAME= 'TABLE_NAME';
```

To drop index:

```
drop index INDEX_NAME;
```

Now it works! :) Quite easy.